# Where should I save the .exe file in Windows HPC Cluster head?

Tags: azure, hpc

I am working on HPC Pack cluster. I want to use the HPC Pack Job Manager to run my tasks.

Where should I save the .exe file?

[Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm9X6.png)

Comment: Probably in the working directory. Did you actually try any of the options?

Comment: I tried before posting  the question but just realized that what I was doing wrong is providing local address instead of the UNC path.

Comment: I am still getting a failure in running my app but I think it is for another reason now. It only says "Task failed during execution with exit code . Please check task's output for error details." but task output is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> If the application is installed on a file share, specify the UNC path to the >executable file. For example, type \\server_name\Program Files\myapp.exe.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919677(v=ws.11).aspx